# Active link/tab in AngularUI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using [AngularUI Router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) and I'm trying to have nested/children links.

All works fine but how do I have selected/active link in Contact tab?

Basically, I need to be able to have selected/active contact one link when the Contact page is loaded. Currently it does not read for some reason the `controlleroneCtrl` unless I click on the link contact one.

```
angular
    .module ('myApp', ['ui.router'
  ])
    .config (['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider',  function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise ('/summary');

        $stateProvider.
            state ('summary', {
            url: '/summary',
            templateUrl: 'summary.html',
            controller: 'summaryCtrl'
          }).
            state ('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'about.html',
            controller: 'aboutCtrl'
          }).
            state ('contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: 'contact.html',
            controller: 'contactoneCtrl'
          })
            // Sub page
            .state('contact.one',{
            url: '/contact.contactone',
            templateUrl: 'one.html',
            controller: 'contactoneCtrl'
          })
            // Sub page
            .state('contact.two',{
            url: '/contact.contacttwo',
            templateUrl: 'two.html',
            controller: 'contacttwoCtrl'
          });

      }]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DWjp5M6kJt2MyBrasfaQ?p=preview

Comment: This will interest you for sure ;):https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/704

Comment: Had trouble with your plunker link

Comment: As @Mik378 said it was a bug solved in 0.2.11 and beyond. Actually updating ui-router.js in the example works properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a much quicker way to do this. Just use the `ui-sref-active="active"` attribute instead of `ui-sref`.

An example:

```
<ul>
    <li ui-sref-active="active">
        <a ui-sref="state">State 1</a>
    <li>
<ul>
```

When the state is active the list item gets the class active. If you want a different class for active states or more than one class, just add it as follows

```
<ul>
    <li ui-sref-active="active so-active super-active">
        <a ui-sref="state">State 1</a>
    <li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the pattern of exposing `state` on the root scope and using `state.current.name` in templates. I justify this global exposure because it's an app-level concern. If your navigation directive has isolate scope you'll need to pass it in, but that's no biggie.

In practice it's been very good for us I think.

Looks like this:

javascript

```
app = angular.module ('myApp', ['ui.router']);
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $state){
  $scope.state = $state;
});
```

html:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active: state.current.name === tab.id}>{{tab.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your solution. The Plunker link should now be working.

Comment: The link does not work for me. Just says "Hello Plunker!". They're kind of tricky, make sure you test the link in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

here is the updated plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/UjjNm4JJIsjb4ydWZRDi?p=preview

**Changes**

1. added a new controller `contactCtrl`
2. setup `$state.go('contact.contactone');` inside the `contactCtrl`
3. updated `app.js` so that `/contact` points to `contactCtrl`

Comment: that's fantastic. Just what I needed. Although, when you navigate a few times between different tabs and then back to contact - the conactone gets disappeared :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `ng-class` like this:

```
ng-class="{active: state.current.name.split('.')[1] === 'homepage'}"
```

My `"state"` name is structured like:

```
app
app.homepage
app.profile
app.profile.user
.etc
```

For example, in my homepage, it's button became like this:

```
<li ng-class="{active: state.current.name.split('.')[1] === 'homepage'}"><a ui-sref="app.homepage">Home</a></li>
```

So just define scope of `$state` like [@Simple As Could Be](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111243/simple-as-could-be) said at root of the app controllers, and you can use `ng-class` to whatever your app's state and how deep your app's state nested.

Answer (score 0):

See my plunk http://embed.plnkr.co/bRfl1S9KXQuvL0Bvt9jD/preview.

Also try updating the version of ui-router to 0.2.12.

Only client tab as really been implemented.