# AngularJS using bootstrap's JS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ngmodel

I am writing an AngularJS app and ran into an issue in combination with bootstrap's js.
If I want the buttons below to act as they should (have 'active' class added when clicked and be exclusive) then I need bootstrap's JS.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
         <input type="radio" value="one" ng-model="myData[$index].number"> one
    </label>    
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" value="two" ng-model="myData[$index].number"> two                                                            
    </label>    
</div>
```

The problem is, that when I use bootstrap's JS, ng-model seems to stop working and no data is shown in my variable.

However, when I remove the bootstrap's JS, ng-model works as expected but the buttons do not act as they should.

I tried replacing bootstrap.js with [angular's ui bootstrap JS](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) but with the same results. I am probably just misunderstanding the use of bootstrap's JS?

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/b3m2T/10/) is the expected behaviour of the buttons. When I use angularJS this doesn't work. 
Unfortunately bootstrap's JS requires jQuery ...

Any help appreciated,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an angular version of Bootstrap's button component. I recommend these from [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##buttons) projects.

Comment: I used UI bootstrap also, and wasn't able to make it work. Also, your first link goes to 404. I might try AngularStrap then, will get back at you

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. If this solves your problem completely, please mark the answer as accepted. Also, I've edited the 404 link.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `bootstrap` with `Angular`'s directive way, use [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). I predict, you want some `function` will be called when the button is clicked? Try not to use `Bootstrap`'s way, use `Angular`'s way. That is `ng-click`. For example in your HTML code:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
     <input type="radio" value="one" ng-model="myData[$index].number" ng-click="call(myData[$index].number)"> one
</label>
```

And your `controller`'s scope should be some kind of:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [*your array here*];
  $scope.call = function(param){
    console.log(param); //your 'myData' index should be printed in console, for example
  };
})
```

Also, your way to create a list of input can be more efficient if using `ng-repeat`, just like:

```
<!-- content is inside of 'myCtrl' scope -->
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" ng-bind="Example.radioGroup">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-repeat="n in radioGroup">
         <input type="radio" value="{{n.number}}" ng-model="n.number"> {{n.text}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Assume if your model has 'number' and 'text' attribute, replace it with what's existing in your `radioGroup` model to show your data in front-end. But if you never use ng-repeat and won't use it now, it can be enhanced later.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use ng-repeat all the time, the example I have is stripped of most real data. I used ui's bootstrap, but how to accomplish 'active' class for each clicked button in a group with exclusive behaviour? I thought bootstrap will handle this(that's the reason I'm using its JS). It would be easy to put 'active' to each button exclusively in jQuery with $(this), but here I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you want to set `active` class in some of your element when clicked? I have some approach, it's rather different for your case, but it's implementable. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26499985/2793961

It's using `ng-class` instead of `Bootstrap`'s approach. Ask me if it's not clearly enough.

Comment: my question aimed a bit differently. Thanks for your part, check the edit

Comment: I have a case like that. Maybe this can help. In your HTML:

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Stream Type</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8 btn-group">
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="data.streamType" btn-radio="'in'">In</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="data.streamType" btn-radio="'out'">Out</label>
      </div>
    </div>

I'm using `Angular` and some of `Bootstrap`, but I don't use `Bootstrap`'s JS at all.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into thus before also. What you need to do is use a `.factory()` recipe thats' appropriate to store your model data, and bind things accordingly in your scope... whether that be a directive or a controller.

Then in your markup, you bind things using ng-bind if you arent already natively within the scope of a controller or directive.

```
   <!-- content is inside of 'myCtrl' scope -->
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" ng-bind="Example.radioGroup">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
             <input type="radio" value="one" ng-model="radioGroup[$index].number"> one
        </label>    
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" value="two" ng-model="radioGroup[$index].number"> two                                                            
        </label>    
    </div>
```

Make sure to inject your factory into your scope. Here's an example of one such factory:

```
myApp.factory('radioFactory', function(){
   return {
       radioGroup: {
           number:["one","two"]
       }
    }
})

myApp.controller ('myCtrl', function($scope,radioFactory){
    $ scope.Example = radioFactory;
})
```

Comment: I dont't have a problem with binding currently, although this is a good example and I might use it in one of the other situations.  The main problem is making the button stay 'active' when clicked on. (or did you give a solution for when I have bootstrap working and binding stops?)

Comment: oops, I burried the lead. What I found was that the issue was the use of ng-model. when I used ng-bind instead (which required rewiring some things), the twitter bootstrap button states worked as intended again. As a side bonus, this is what caused me to learn how to really model my angular apps, since that kind of data shouldn't be in a controller in most well built apps.